# Video playing in webview always hiding other views?

Tags: android, video, webview

I have a webview that's playing a video, and I want it to appear behind some other views, but I can't seem to make it happen. I've tried simply just sending the foreground views to the front with `bringChildToFront(View v)`, but no cigar. Any thoughts?

Edit: Some more details: The webview plays a video using flash, and the webview is the size of the entire screen. I have some stuff I want to pop up in front of the video, but they only stay behind the video. They're definitely there, as they receive touch events and stuff, but just hidden away from view by the video.

Comment: Is the video being played in Flash, HTML5, or something else? When the video is playing, is only the video in front, or does the webpage's text come with it?

Comment: @notverycreative: Added some more details. The video is the only thing playing, as I'm loading it directly rather than embedded within a webpage.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I think this is an issue with the Flash player rather than your app, because other apps that have Flash enabled in a WebView with other Views on top of it have the exact same issue (Pulse, namely). I don't even think this is something you as a developer can fix; rather, you'll have to wait and hope that Adobe gets their act together and fixes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Flash player will essentially pre-empt any other views in the window, you'll just have to do one better over Flash: use another window on top of the main window.

Android allows you to do this by using the [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) class.